# DbiX::Class / Creating tree of test data without persisting

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I'm using [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class) as or mapper for my Perl project. When it comes to generating test data I'm using [DBIx::Class::ResultSet::new](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSet#new) to create new entities in memory. In order to link entities with relationships I use [set_from_related](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Relationship::Base#set_from_related). This works absolutely flawless until I try to set the value(s) for a [has_many](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Relationship#has_many) relationship. Pseudo example:

```
# Table 'AUTHOR' has 
#   one-to-one  (belongs_to) relationship named 'country' to table 'COUNTRY'
#   one-to-many (has_many) relationship named 'books' to table 'BOOK'
my $s       = Schema::getSchema();
my $author  = $s->resultset('Author')->new({ name => 'Jon Doe', year_of_birth => 1982 });
my $country = $s->resultset('Country')->new({ name => 'Germany', iso_3166_code => 'DE' }); 
my $book    = $s->resultset('Book')->new({ title => 'A star far away', publishing_year => 2002 });

# Now let's make 'em known to each other
$author->set_from_related('country', $country);
$author->set_from_related('books',   $book);

# At this point
#   $author->country      is defined
#   $author->books->first is undef    <<<---- Problem
```

I cannot find a suitable method in the [DBIx::Class::Relationship::Base](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Relationship::Base#set_from_related) documentation. The one closest to what I need is [add_to_$rel](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Relationship::Base#add_to_$rel) but this method creates (persists) the entities. This is not an option for me as some of the entites used in my project don't belong to me (no write permission).

Does anyone have an idea how to add entities in memory for a [has_many](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Relationship#has_many) relationship ?

Comment: Have you considered running your entire test in a transaction and to roll it back afterwards?

Comment: Or it might be smarter to deploy a test database to use for your tests, and to actually round-trip.

Comment: @simbabque
I cannot make use of your first suggestion to use a transaction as I still don't have write permissions to several of the used tables. The second idea to deploy a test database is a possibility but needs far more effort than I wanted to invest. Still voting up :-)

Comment: Write permissions? That's interesting. I thought you're talking about unit tests. So what is it you want to test then?

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible as newly created result objects don't have their primary key column(s) populated until they are persisted to the database.
What you possibly want is to use multi-create and run that inside a transaction.

Comment: Multi-Create is not possible. As I wrote I do not have and will never have write permissions for several used tables/entities.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that in your post. Are some of the result objects existing rows? If so load them from the database instead of creating them in-memory and use them in the multi-create.
Please describe your use case, why do you want to create in-memory only DBIx::Class::Result objects?

Comment: Well as I mentioned it's for creating test data. Some entities of the data structure are part of my database scheme (writable) some are part of a foreign one (not writable). I'm using generated Data::Faker Modules to generate HashRefs which I'm using as value sets for in memory created DBIx::Class objects. The whole ER is quite big and complicated and I need to be able to generate the test data independently from maybe existing records (can't be guaranteed to exists) for unit testing.

Comment: It would be way easier to have a writable database instead of the production read-only one for testing. You should never mix test and production databases from a (data) security standpoint. It might be sufficient for your tests if the team responsible for the foreign database provides you with a read-only test database you can use instead of the production one.